# How to set type of class method?

Tags: typescript

I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
  handler (mutations) {
    // logic
  }
}
```

The `handler` method should be a function that processes [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) mutations. There are built-in types for `MutationObserver`, specifically:

```
interface MutationCallback {
    (mutations: MutationRecord[], observer: MutationObserver): void;
}
```

How do I tell TypeScript that `handler` of `Foo` should be `MutationCallback`?

## I tried

### #1

```
class Foo {
  handler: MutationCallback = function (mutations) {
    // logic
  }
}
```

But the compiled code is this:

```
var Foo = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.handler = function (mutations) {
            // logic
        };
    }
    return Foo;
}());
```

The `handler` is treated as an instance property and is not set on `Foo.prototype`, and I don't want that. The compiled code should look like this:

```
var Foo = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.prototype.handler = function (mutations) {
        // logic
    };
    return Foo;
}());
```

### #2

```
interface Foo {
  handler: MutationCallback
}

class Foo {
  handler (mutations) {
    // logic
  }
}
```

But TypeScript gives the error:

> Duplicate identifier 'handler'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create interface for your `Foo` type and define that handler should be of type `MutationCallback`

```
interface IFoo {
    handler: MutationCallback
}


class Foo implements IFoo {
  handler(mutations: MutationRecord[], observer: MutationObserver) {
    // logic
  }
}

interface MutationCallback {
    (mutations: MutationRecord[], observer: MutationObserver): void;
}
```